# Mysql cache set : How to test on website

Tags: php, mysql

I executed below query to to set mysql cache, all query executed successfully but how to test what is cached and used in website from this cache.

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL query_cache_size = 1000000;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'query_cache_size';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your `query_cache_type` variable is also set to `ON`, you can check via

```
SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Qcache%';
```

`Qcache_hits` tells you, if a query was read from cache, `Qcache_inserts` if a query was put into cache, `Qcache_not_cached` which queries were not cached.

Comment: Seriously, why don't you just google the manual? And what's so hard to understand about the output? Play around with. Do the `SHOW STATUS...`, then `SELECT something...` and do `SHOW STATUS...` again. Then see what's the difference. Most probably `Qcache_inserts` will be incremented by 1. So, what could this mean? Play around to learn or just read manual.

Comment: If I change some records or add some new records in table. In this case how query cache will work? Will it update cache with new result or we have to clear cache.

Comment: Again, why don't you simply just try it out. It's a great way to learn. If you update your table, all queries regarding the table will be removed from query cache. And inserted again with the next select. You don't have to manage the query cache, MySQL does this by itself.